# How to show icon for spinner and open list on click

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to show icon for spinner and on click open the list with highlighted selected position.

here's my method for add item in spinner :

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner() {
    try {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Top Stories");
        list.add("Recent");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sortspinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

thanks for hlpe..

Comment: @Vyger all i want is just a icon (no text) if list is closed, and simple text list when list is opne.