# Use an Icon for Android Spinner for a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have a fragment that programmatically adds a spinner to supportactionbar, the result isn't pretty:

[image: collapsed]
[image: Expanded]

How can I have an Icon instead of the text when the spinner is collapsed?
there's already a question missing an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423632/how-to-show-icon-for-spinner-and-open-list-on-click)

P.S. The spinner data is static, so I can use another component if I can achieve a better result.

Comment: try this [this](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107)